# Will the number of stripes in Striped.lazyWeakReadWriteLock(int stripes) stripes grow as needed?

Tags: java, concurrency, guava

Trying to decide number of stripes when calling `Striped.lazyWeakReadWriteLock(int stripes)`

Javadoc says:
`@param stripes the minimum number of stripes (locks) required`

Why does it say *minimum* in the javadoc? This lead me to believe that number of stripes is just the initial capacity and it will grow as needed and shrink back to the *minimum* number set at construction.
Looking at code however it seems that the number of stripes is fixed.

Should I be doing: `Striped.lazyWeakReadWriteLock(maximum_number_of_stripes)`
Or 
`Striped.lazyWeakReadWriteLock(10)` and expect it to grow?

I already wrote unit test and that confirmed that it has to be 
`Striped.lazyWeakReadWriteLock(maximum_number_of_stripes)`

So question is more about trying to interpret the javadoc. Why does it say *minimum*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the *minimum* because the implementation allocates a fixed number of stripes that is at least that number.

In particular, if you look at the implementation, it is rounded up to a power of two to make it particularly efficient to compute which stripe a given hash is mapped to.